# python when adding values from a file to a list. only add the first column from that list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, import

i am trying to add values from two seperate files into two seperate lists. the first file `testing.predict` only have one value per line and therefor create and print out the list fine.

the other file `testing` have 14 values per line. however i just want to add the first value of each line to the list. each row in `testing`is laid out like: `-1 2 5 2 77 4 3 76 2 9 0 2 3 8`.

```
with open('testing.predict', 'r') as x:
      predictList = [line.strip() for line in x]

print predictList

with open('testing', 'r') as y:
      originalList = [line.strip() for line in y]

print originalList
```

when i print out `originalList` it produces:

```
['1 1:1 2:5 3:0 4:1 5:3 6:2 7:1 8:18 9:30 10:50 11:13 12:12 13:24', 
'-1 1:0 2:1 3:0 4:0 5:1 6:1 7:1 8:10 9:10 10:12 11:10 12:6 13:16', 
'1 1:0 2:7 3:0 4:0 5:4 6:4 7:1 8:21 9:30 10:46 11:19 12:11 13:25', 
'-1 1:0 2:1 3:0 4:0 5:1 6:1 7:1 8:2 9:4 10:3 11:4 12:2 13:5', 
'-1 1:0 2:1 3:0 4:0 5:1 6:1 7:1 8:4 9:4 10:7 11:3 12:6 13:6', 
'-1 1:0 2:1 3:0 4:0 5:1 6:1 7:1 8:3 9:3 10:3 11:3 12:3 13:4', 
'-1 1:2 2:1 3:0 4:0 5:1 6:1 7:1 8:8 9:7 10:12 11:5 12:5 13:12',... ]
```

i only want it to print out:

```
['1','-1','1','-1','-1,'-1','-1'... ]
```

as you can see it only saves the first value from each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `split` the line and keep just the first space-separated string:

```
with open('testing', 'r') as y:
    originalList = [line.strip().split()[0] for line in y]
```

If you want the values as integers, not strings, then of course

```
    originalList = [int(line.strip().split()[0]) for line in y]
```